How to secure AWS credentials when running node-pty in a containerized code execution system?
I'm working on a prototype project similar to Replit, where users can execute code inside a containerized environment. Each time a user starts a playground, I spin up a new container for code execution. I’ve set up:

A socket server to manage communication.
node-pty to create a forked
terminal and provide read/write access to users via a web-based
terminal.

Problem:
I need to use AWS services for storage and other backend operations. The issue is that when the Node.js application (acting as a bridge) is connected to the terminal using node-pty, the AWS credentials can potentially be exposed to the user. Since the terminal gives users access to run commands, I'm worried they can access environment variables or other sensitive information, including my AWS credentials.
What I've tried:
I have try to create a non root user who have access to specific folder (as per username). but when run container with this non root user can not access to run main bridge(nodejs) application.
Question:
What are some best practices to prevent sensitive information like AWS credentials from being exposed in this kind of architecture? How can I securely manage AWS credentials when spinning up containers for users to run code while still giving them terminal access? Are there any recommended patterns or strategies for securing credentials in such use cases?
Reference Video:

https://youtu.be/EiOvxYja8GU?si=8w8FXbTZeD64w4IR
https://youtu.be/s0kBqGpThp0?si=1mvYqEHVN2a6yGZo

Github repo

https://github.com/shaileshjadav/cloud-ide


This is a hard problem in general: you also need to make sure the absolutely-untrusted code can't do things like make network connections into your internal infrastructure, and you want to avoid running things like cryptocurrency miners.  Do you actually need to run this?  Is there a specific programming-oriented problem you're running into?

@DavidMaze, Thanks! but currently i don't care to run cryptocurrency miners. I want to build project for our internal use case.

If the end user is providing the code and your infrastructure is running it, how will you prevent it?

@DavidMaze I will run code of user in seperate temporatory container of ubuntu.
